# 4 cell battery management circuit

Tags: mosfet, batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, battery-monitor

[image]

I am making a battery management system for a device I am making. I am connecting 4 Li-on 18650 cells. I would like it to be on the same board as my microcontroller so an off the shelf won't do.

- Circuit A allows the microcontroller to drive Cn to 3.3 V and drain each cell individually where the top is connected to cell BAT_Cn and the bottom to the next cell: BAT_Cn-1. I know it will drain the battery VERY slowly. This will be active every time the batteries are charged so speed is not a requirement. Are there any glaring mistakes here that will make this not work? Is it OK that Vgd will be -13.5 V for the highest cell?
- Circuit B is used to measure the voltage of the cell. The microcontroller drives Mn to 3.3 V to make current flow across the series resistors which are chosen to make the voltage of Sn = 3.3 V when BAT_Cn is at its maximum. Will that MOSFET configuration correctly control power to the series resistors and be able to control the battery sensing?

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Existing BMS ICs have already solved the problems you don't even realize you have, and do not introduce the problems that you don't even realize you've introduced:

- Circuit A doesn't drain a single cell, it also drains the cells beneath it.
- Circuit B introduces an error in the measurement that is inconsistent between the cells. It also drains the cells during measurement.

Instead, look for complete 4S BMS ICs in the web sites of companies like Texas Instruments: https://www.ti.com/power-management/battery-management/protectors/products.html#1152max=2%3B5&